# CodeIgniter 4 - No direct script access allowed

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

After installing and configuring CI 4 I can see the home controller and the debug bar as normal (I'm in development mode).

There is a problem with error reporting. **If I try to deliberately write some wrong PHP code, CodeIgniter overrides the normal PHP behaviour and hides the errors (in development mode!!).**

Here's an example of deliberately adding a PHP error to the home controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        this is an error!! ()
        return view('welcome_message');
    }

}
```

Here's the output (which is not helpful with real errors):

```
No direct script access allowed
```

How can I set CodeIgniter 4 to show PHP errors? (the error is not even logged anywhere inside the server)

Comment: Are you able to route to other routes ? Chances are this issue is with Apache not PHP error reporting itself.

Comment: Hi Dhaval, actually, the issue was Composer. I installed CI normally without Composer and everything worked fine (not a Composer expert and it's not needed given as we are not a multinational enterprise with Composer developers).

Answer (score 0):

this problem happened when u delete this folder **(app/view/errors)** from **view**